# Reducing the complexity of the data in text file

Tags: text-processing, awk, perl

I have this file:

```
  1  2
  2  7
  3  4
  4  7
  5  3
  6  7
  7  1
  8  2
  9  4
```

And my desired output is

```
 1 13
 2 17
 3 7
```

In my input i have 9 rows and i want to reduce it to three rows while preserving the total amount of 2nd column. For example 1 in 1st column represnts 1,2,3 and 13 in 2nd column, 1st row represent addition (2+4+7) and so on.. Any idea? may be by using awk/ perl or any other linux tool.

Comment: It is feasible to combine things for every 3 rows, but that underlines a problem with the way the original file was generated as there is no key->value relationship anywhere.

Comment: Yes, there is no relation whatsoever. This is just a dummy file but i want to do this.

Comment: Are you asking how to sum every three rows?

Comment: and also combining them at the same time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an `awk` solution:

```
awk '{ s+=$2; if (!(NR%3)) { k++; print k,s; s=0 } };
     END { if (NR%3) { k++; print k, s } }' file.txt
```

It ignores the first column, preferring to generate it in `k` as an output row number. The second column is summed in `s`, and every three lines (`(NR % 3) == 0`) it's output and the accumulator reset. Finally, if we have any left-over lines we output the remaining sum.

Output from the example file

```
1 13
2 17
3 7
```

---

Just for completeness, here is a [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) version that uses a function to handle the repeated code from the modulo-3 and END blocks:

```
awk 'function outsum() { print ++k,s; s=0 };
     { s+=$2; if (!(NR%3)) { outsum() } };
     END { if (NR%3) { outsum() } }' file.txt
```

Comment: I'd change the condition in the END block to `if (NR%3)` in case there is a 10th line with a value 0. I'd also be DRY and use a function to increment and print.

Comment: @glennjackman I looked at using a function and while the code was more elegant it was actually longer. Since the OP asked for a one-liner I took the shorter route. Thank you for suggestion re `NR%3`; incorporated.

Comment: meh, one-liner: `awk '{sum += $2} function p() {print ++c, sum; sum=0} NR%3==0 {p()} END {if (NR%3) p()}'`

Comment: @glennjackman I'll go home now

Answer (score 3):

Perl solution:

```
perl -lane '
    $s += $F[1];
    print(join "\t", ++$l, $s), $s = 0
        if 0 == $. % 3 || eof;
' input-file
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-a` splits each line on whitespace into the @F array
- `$s` is used as a variable keeping the sum
- `$.` is a special variable that contains the input line number
- `$l` is the output line number

Answer (score 1):

This should maybe go to [codegolf.SE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).  Here is a one liner **without** `perl`, `awk` or `sed`:

```
paste <(for i in $(seq 1 0.33333333334 $(A=$(wc -l input.dat | cut -d ' ' -f 1); echo $A/3+1 | bc)); do echo $i/1 | bc; done) <(tr -s ' ' < input.dat | cut -d ' ' -f 3) | datamash -g 1 sum 2
```

---

#### In detail

The left side

```
for i in $(seq 1 0.33333333334 $(A=$(wc -l input.dat | cut -d ' ' -f 1); echo $A/3+1 | bc)); do echo $i/1 | bc; done
```

Produces a list like (it accounts for the actual number of lines in the input file):

```
1
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
3
```

And the right side

```
tr -s ' ' < input.dat | cut -d ' ' -f 3
```

Chops first column of the input file leaving:

```
2
7
4
7
3
7
1
2
4
```

`paste` combines them back and [`datamash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) does the *group by*.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another oneliner with `sed` and `dc`:

```
sed 's/ *[^ ]*//' < input.dat | tr "\n" " " | sed 's/\([^ ]\+\) *\([^ ]\+\) *\([^ ]\+\)/\1 \2 \3++p/g' | dc | cat -n
```

Explanation:

```
sed 's/ *[^ ]*//' < input.dat
```

Kills the first column; a bit more robust than `cut` against repeated spaces

```
tr "\n" " "
```

Transforms all the newlines in spaces, thus putting everything on one line

```
sed 's/\([^ ]\+\) *\([^ ]\+\) *\([^ ]\+\)/\0++p/g'
```

Replaces three space-delimited tokens with themselves followed by `++p`.

```
dc
```

Feeds the output in `dc`, the RPN calculator; each number gets pushed on the stack, and every three you have `+`, `+` and `p` commands (`+` means sum the two numbers on the top of the stack, `p` prints the stack). This gives us the second column of output.

```
cat -n
```

Rewrites everything adding the line numbers.

Comment: The `-s` (squeeze) in `tr` makes a better weapon against repeated spaces, for example: `tr -s ' ' < input.dat | cut -d ' ' -f 3`.

Comment: @grochmal: yes, but it's longer =) in my mind here I'm still on PCG

Comment: To the downvoter: mind to explain?

Comment: Someone just went through **all** answers here and downvoted them.  That's a form of blind downvoting, it just happens.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that uses only shell commands. I've split it out across several lines but there's no reason why you couldn't roll it all together as a one-liner (that's how it started):

```
(
    s=0 k=1 n=0
    while read x v
    do
        s=$((s+v)) n=$((n+1))
        if [[ n -eq 3 ]]
        then
            echo $k $s
            k=$((k+1)) n=0 s=0
        fi
    done
    [[ s -gt 0 ]] && echo $k $s
) <file.txt
```

---

```
( s=0 k=1 n=0; while read x v; do s=$((s+v)) n=$((n+1)); if [[ n -eq 3 ]]; then echo $k $s; k=$((k+1)) n=0 s=0; fi; done; [[ s -gt 0 ]] && echo $k $s ) <file.txt
```